# Automation of Mainframe jobs using Selenium WebDriver/JAVA

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

In our project, we are using Selenium Web driver to automate web application.For one of the application, we need to submit a mainframe jobs and then only a data will be available for next application.

As we were not able to automate mainframe jobs, there is always gap between two application and we were not able to achieve end to end scenarios.

Does anyone have any idea on automating mainframe session using JAVA/Web Driver.

I came to know about Jameleon/Jagacy Driver. But not much information is available.

Its really helpful to me if someone share thoughts on achieving this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can ftp your job using Java. Which you can add into your Selenium test

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/systems/library/es-batch-zos.html

If FTP isnt open on your firewall try telnet

Comment: thanks for your comments. I tried using FTP client and understood that through FTP we can pass text file and cannot run any existing job in mainframe. Please correct me if i'm wrong. i have an existing job in mainframe. I need to submit those jobs using java.

Comment: If you have an existing job you can use Telnet or Java to execute them.

Answer (score 0):

Please try submitting the mainframe job through batch file and then trigger this batch file through Java.

Answer (score 0):

For future searchs:

You can submits your job and waits spool to finish.

https://github.com/naskarlab/java-mainframe-tools

```
JESClient ftp = new JESClient();
ftp.connect("192.168.15.101");
if(!ftp.login("IBMUSER","SYS1")) {
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Error on connect.");
}

JESJob job1 = ftp.submit(this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/jcl/NKCOMP.jcl"));

logger.info(job1.toString());
job1.waitComplete(120);

logger.info(job1.waitSpool(3));
logger.info(job1.getSpool());
```